# unable to change URL by using getRequestDispatcher

Tags: java, servlets

The code i use for this is

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("jsp/caseconference.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

The code above works fine when i use `send Redirect` but in that part, I can't use request and response which gives an error.

Comment: We need more details to help you. Are you doing this in your `doPost` method? Does your `doPost` method take `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse` as parameters? Are you forwarding the correct path? You should post more code as well as the error you are getting so that we may be able to help you.

Comment: yes thank you for reply i'm using doPost method problem is only this that when i use request.getRequestDispatcher("jsp/caseconference.jsp").forward(request, response); this gives me name of servlet  like this https://localhost:8443/roswellpark/LoginServlet but i just want the URL like https://localhost:8443/roswellpark/caseconference

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment above, I don't think you're getting an error, but rather, you want the last part of your url to go from `LoginServlet` to `caseconference`. You would have to create a url pattern for `caseconference` like this:

```
@WebServlet(
        name = "LoginServlet",
        description = "This is optional but helpful",
        urlPatterns = "/caseconference"
)
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
    ....
}
```

Then create a variable in your `doPost` method to keep track of every path the user is on, for example:

`String path = request.getServletPath();`

Whenever the time comes for the user to redirect to `roswellpark/caseconference` set the path to `caseconference`:

`path = "/caseconference";`

Then, build your url like this, provided you have a folder in your directory named `roswellpark` or you make a url pattern for it:

`String url = "roswellpark/" + path + ".jsp";`

And lastly, forward the url using try/catch statements for best practice:

`try{
 request.getRequestDispatcher(url).forward(request,response);
}catch(Exception ex){
....
}`